# Efficient calculation for Lerch Transcendent Expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, riemann-zeta, polylogarithm, summation-method

I've encountered:
$$\Phi(z, s, \alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac { z^k} {(k+\alpha)^s}.$$

When trying to compute:

$$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{p=0}^m \frac{2}{(2p-1)\ x^{2p-1}}\ s.t. x\in\mathbb{N} =\ ???$$ which (by [Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%202%2F%28%282p-1%29x%5E%282p-1%29%29%20from%20p%20%3D1%20to%20m)):
$$???\ =\ \frac{2}{x}\tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}) - \frac{\Phi(\frac{1}{x^2}, 1, m+\frac{1}{2})}{x^{2(m+1)}}$$

Unfortunately, $$ \frac{\Phi(\frac{1}{x^2}, 1, m+\frac{1}{2})}{x^{2(m+1)}} = \frac {1}{x^{2(m+1)}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {1} {(k+m+\frac{1}{2})x^{2k}}$$

Which doesn't quite help me. Need an efficient way to calculate/estimate this, ideally a convergent formula.

Please see pages 1-5 of the following resource: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.01122.pdf

From the following question, [Summing Lerch Transcendents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175038/summing-lerch-transcendents), for possible leads.

Comment: For an overview of the numerics see e.g. <a href="https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.12065">arXiv:2303.12065</a>

Comment: @R.J.Mathar Do you have the formula as well?

Comment: I had a very similar problem a few years ago and I am still stuck.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar' s provided resource introduces a new parameter almost every line. Makes things a tad difficult to track, but I think the error term for $s=1$ has a removable singularity, and truncation is possible using quadrature. Still looking for a nice formula like the Euler-Maclaurin.

Comment: For alternatives see https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05928  related to https://upcommons.upc.edu/handle/2117/171403 , or https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.048 or http://aksenov.freeshell.org/lerchphi.html

Comment: Right but we're looking for bounded error formulas, @R.J.Mathar

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici another way to attack this, but I need help calculating this integral Wolfram Alpha can't/won't in short order: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745361/forbidden-integral-deceptively-simple-integral-wolfram-alpha-refuses-to-compute